# R finding a substring in a column that's in a vector of strings

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently working in R in data.table and am having issues using %like% to mark if a column is containing a substring found in a vector of strings. As a background, this data set contains several misspellings of the same word. For example, diarrhea can be spelled dirrhea, diarrhoea, and diarrhea. I need to catch them all.

Here is a sample of the table I'm working with

```
pid  diagnosis
1    pneumonia/diarrhea
2    diarrhea
3    cough+diarrhea
4    cold_dirrhea
5    feverdiarrhoea
6    meningitis
7    malaria
8    chicken pox
```

Here is the resulting table I want:

```
pid  diagnosis           diarrhea
1    pneumonia/diarrhea  1 
2    diarrhea            1
3    cough+diarrhea      1
4    cold_dirrhea        1
5    feverdiarrhoea      1
6    meningitis          NA
7    malaria             NA
8    chicken pox         NA
```

I have tried the following code without success:

```
diarrhea_var<-c("diarrhea", "diarrhoea", "dirrhea")

dt[diagnosis %like% diarrhea_var, diarrhea:=1]
dt[diagnosis %like% diarrhea_var, diarrhea:=1]

The code above produces the following error: Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there another method I can use that would achieve the desired results?

Comment: It is because your pattern is length 3. You can use `paste()` to collapse your pattern with `"|"`: `dt[diagnosis %like% paste(diarrhea_var, collapse = "|"), diarrhea := 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(diarrhea = +(grepl(paste0(diarrhea_var, collapse = '|'), diagnosis))) %>% 
mutate(diarrhea = na_if(diarrhea, 0))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
    pid diagnosis          diarrhea
  <dbl> <chr>                 <int>
1     1 pneumonia/diarrhea        1
2     2 diarrhea                  1
3     3 cough+diarrhea            1
4     4 cold_dirrhea              1
5     5 feverdiarrhoea            1
6     6 meningitis               NA
7     7 malaria                  NA
8     8 chicken pox              NA
>
```